# Why is calculated value not recognized as a number?

Tags: calculations, lua

In the code below I want to proceed with a calculated result (from Lualatex). But the calculated value (rounded) is not recognized as a number. Who knows a solution for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
    local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
    if num >= 0 then return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
    else return math.ceil(num * mult - 0.5) / mult end
end

sqrt = math.sqrt
function treq (t, s, p, k, w, a) 
    return k *s * sqrt(p / w) + a 
end

function PROCEED (a, b) 
    return a / f 
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\round[2][0]{% default value of opt. param.: 0
   \directlua{tex.sprint(round(#2,#1))}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
Let's try macro 'round':
$ \sqrt{2} \approx \round[1]{2^(1/2)} $ OK.
$ \sqrt[5]{32} = \round{32^(1/5)} $ OK.
$ 1.699999 \approx \round[5]{1.699999} $ OK.
$ -1.699999 \approx \round[1]{-1.699999} $ Also OK.
$ -1.9 \approx \round{-1.9} $ OK.
$ 8 \approx \round[-1]{8} $ OK.\\

Let's try macro 'round' in calculations:
\def\t{3}
\def\s{454}
\def\p{4.51}
\def\k{0.0039413}
\def\w{7.04}
\def\a{1.5}
\def\treq{\round[3]{\luadirect{tex.print(treq(\t,\s,\p,\k,\w,\a))}}} 

$ k = \round[4]{\k} $. OK.
$ t_{req} =\treq $ OK there is an answer (and rounded) \\

Let's try macro 'round' in proceeding calculations:
\def\A{\round[3]{\luadirect{tex.print(PROCEED(\t,2))}}} 
\def\B{\round[3]{\luadirect{tex.print(PROCEED(\treq,2))}}}

$ A =\A $ macro 'PROCEED' works with $t=\t$
$ B =\B $ macro 'PROCEED' is NOT working  with $t_{req}=\treq!\\$

Why is rounded value 'treq' NOT applicable in further calculations?

\end{document}
```

Comment: your example is incomplete and so can't be tested.

Comment: you say `A=\A` works but I get `[\directlua]:13: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (global 'f')
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:13: in function 'PROCEED'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luadirect ... { \luacode@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
                                                  
l.50 $ A =\A
           $ macro 'PROCEED' works with $t=\t$
`

Comment: oh that is a typo in PROCEED  you meant a/b not a/f  (I think)

Comment: Yes it should have been a/b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command `\treq` uses `\round` which is not expandable as it has an optional argument, so it does not expand to a numeric value when passed to Lua

Using a mandatory argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
    local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
    if num >= 0 then return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
    else return math.ceil(num * mult - 0.5) / mult end
end

sqrt = math.sqrt
function treq (t, s, p, k, w, a) 
    return k *s * sqrt(p / w) + a 
end

function PROCEED (a, b) 
    return a / b 
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\round[2]{% default value of opt. param.: 0
   \directlua{tex.sprint(round(#2,#1))}}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
Let's try macro 'round':
$ \sqrt{2} \approx \round{1}{2^(1/2)} $ OK.
$ \sqrt[5]{32} = \round0{32^(1/5)} $ OK.
$ 1.699999 \approx \round{5}{1.699999} $ OK.
$ -1.699999 \approx \round{1}{-1.699999} $ Also OK.
$ -1.9 \approx \round0{-1.9} $ OK.
$ 8 \approx \round{-1}{8} $ OK.\\

Let's try macro 'round' in calculations:
\def\t{3}
\def\s{454}
\def\p{4.51}
\def\k{0.0039413}
\def\w{7.04}
\def\a{1.5}
\def\treq{\round{3}{\luadirect{tex.print(treq(\t,\s,\p,\k,\w,\a))}}} 

$ k = \round{4}{\k} $. OK.
$ t_{req} =\treq $ OK there is an answer (and rounded) 

Let's try macro 'round' in proceeding calculations:
\def\A{\round{3}{\luadirect{tex.print(PROCEED(\t,2))}}} 
\def\B{\round{3}{\luadirect{tex.print(PROCEED(\treq,2))}}}

$ A =\A $ macro 'PROCEED' works with $t=\t$
$ B =\B $ macro 'PROCEED' is NOT working  with $t_{req}=\treq!\\$

Why is rounded value 'treq' NOT applicable in further calculations?

\end{document}
```

You could use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` to define an expandable version of `\round` with an optional argument, but I don't think I would here.